# single regex not working for a three different patterns

Tags: regex, perl

I need a optimal regexp to match all these three types of texts in a text file.

1. [TRUE,FALSE]
2. [4,5,6,7]
3. [2-15]

i am trying the following regex match which is not working

```
m/([0-9A-Fa-fx,]+)\s*[-~,]\s*([0-9A-Fa-fx,]+)/)
```

Comment: What do you mean by `not working`?

Comment: the T, R, and U in TRUE are not matched by your regex

Answer (score 3):

```
/
   (?(DEFINE)
      (?<WORD> [a-zA-Z]+ )
      (?<NUM>  [0-9]+ )
   )

   \[ \s*
   (?: (?&WORD) (?: \s* , \s* (?&WORD) )+
   |   (?&NUM) (?: \s* , \s* (?&NUM) )+
   |   (?&NUM) \s* - \s* (?&NUM)
   )
   \s* \]
/x
```

Comment: @rjh, You can inline the definitions if you want to avoid 5.10 features, but then you have to edit the definitions in two or four places if you want to make a change.

Answer (score 2):

`4-7` is a subset of `2-15`.  This regex should capture them:

```
/TRUE|FALSE|[2-9]|1[0-5]/
```

Comment: I don't get how this could possibly match `[4,5,6,7]`. I mean, it does match, but only the first decimal. I think you're interpreting too much into the (incomplete) problem description.

Answer (score 0):

A quick'n'dirty test program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

for my $line (<DATA>) {

    chomp $line;
    print "$line: ";

    if ($line =~ /
            ^                                   # beginning of the string
            \[                                  # a literal opening sq. bracket
            (                                   # alternatives:
                  (TRUE|FALSE) (,(TRUE|FALSE))*     # one or more thruth words
                | (\d+) (,\d+)*                     # one or more numbers
                | (\d+) - (\d+)                     # a range of numbers
            )                                   # end of alternatives
            \]                                  # a literal closing sq. bracket
            $                                   # end of the string
        /x) {

        print "match\n";
    }
    else {
        print "no match\n";
    }
}

__DATA__
[TRUE]
foo
[FALSE,TRUE,FALSE]
[FALSE,TRUE,]
[42,FALSE]
[17,42,666]
bar
[17-42]
[17,42-666]
```

Output:

```
[TRUE]: match
foo: no match
[FALSE,TRUE,FALSE]: match
[FALSE,TRUE,]: no match
[42,FALSE]: no match
[17,42,666]: match
bar: no match
[17-42]: match
[17,42-666]: no match
```